# How to generate an c function directly to excutable machine code?

Tags: c, gcc, compilation

My file is bootpack.c and it has a function `void f() { while(1); }` in it.
I want to generate it directly to excutable machine code. So I compile it like this:

```
gcc -c -nostdinc -fno-builtin bootpack.c
ld -nostdlib file.o -o bootpack.bin
```

But I find that bootpack.bin is 3.84KB. It is should only be a few bytes, I thought, because it is just a loop. What is wrong? And how to generate this file correctly?

Comment: You created an object file, not an executable.  The extra bytes are the description of the code for the linker.

Comment: then how to generate an executable file from the object file? thanks,

Comment: You'll need to have the correct descriptive information in the executable so that the process loader can find the entry point for where the program starts.  By default, that is provided by the linker, based on code in an object file with a name such as `crt0.o` specified by the compiler.  You will have to tell it about your alternative entry point so that the system knows where the program will start running.  The executable will still be a few KiB because of the support information — the ELF headers and sections.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `binary` as output format for the GNU (BFD-based) linker:

```
ld -nostdlib file.o --oformat=binary -o bootpack.bin
```

You can then disassemble that with:

```
objdump -b binary -m i386 -D bootpack.bin
```

(substitute your target architecture in place of `i386`).

Comment: As compile my file as what you said on windows7.But it is said:"ld:can not perform PE operations on non PE output file bootpack.bin"

Answer (score 0):

Because it contain symbol table information ,to reduce the size of executable you can use strip command .

Use it as "strip --strip-all  executable-file-name" so it will remove extra information such as symbol table etc.  Even in gcc option -s can be used , there are more option in gcc which can be used  .

Comment: OK , I tried this, but bootpack.bin is still 2KB, much bigger than I thought.